# Lyapunov equation and Time-varying homogeneous system

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

Consider the following time-varying homogeneous system $\dot{x}(t)=A(t)x(t)$.
Assume that there exist an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix $Q(t)$ that satisfies
$$\nu I\leq Q(t)\leq \rho I,$$
$$A^T(t)Q(t)+Q(t)A(t)+\dot{Q}(t)\leq 0,$$
where $\nu,\rho$ are positive constants.
Show that given system is uniformly stable under this condition.

Some things that I found might be useful:

Definition: $x_e$ is uniformly stable iff for $\varepsilon>0,\exists\delta=\delta(\varepsilon)>0$ s.t. $\left\|x_0-x_e\right\|\leq\delta \Rightarrow \left\|x(t;t_0,x_0)-x_e\right\|\leq\varepsilon,\forall t\geq t_0.$
Theorem: All eigenvalues of $A$ have negative real parts ($\dot{x}(t)=A(t)x(t)$ is stable) iff for any given positive definite symmetry matrix $N$, the Lyapunov equation $$A^TM+MA=-N$$ has a unique symmetric solution $M$ and $M$ is positive definite.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Math SE! Please post what you've tried, so people here can help you understand the things that you are having trouble with. Please remember that this website is **not** a homework website. Thank you!

Comment: The negative eigenvalues work for a constant matrix $A$ only. You need to check the Lyapunov function theorems and consider the Lyapunov function $V = x^\top Q x$.